# Docker Jenkins images login error

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm new to docker, i trying to use jenkins on docker. So I pull jenkins image with this command

```
docker pull jenkins
```

Jenkins installed without any error. After that i started jenkins image like the document said. https://hub.docker.com/r/_/jenkins/

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

So I tried to login `http://localhost:8080/` but I got login error. And its said go to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging for check. I checked and I need to open  `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` file to generated admin password. 
I tried to reach that filed with `bash`. I didn't get the file.

How can I reach the file ? How to reach my generated password or jenkins files on docker etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The password was saved to `/var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword`.
You can use

```
docker exec <container> cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

where `<container>` is your container id or name.

Comment: it says "cat: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword: No such file or directory"

Comment: let me try it from the begining

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the volume, or you deleted it accidentally. Try it with `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-test:/var/jenkins_home --name test-jenkins -d jenkins && docker exec test-jenkins cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

Comment: it works thanks a lot. when i run this command, its show generated password file at start

Comment: I found some documentation with `--volume jenkins-data...` instead of `--volumen jenkins-test...`. It was by my installation the problem: `jenkins-test` it to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach volume to jenkins in Yml file then you don't need to look inside container. Just go to your system folder path and check  path/folder/secrets/initialAmdinPassword

```
 volumes:
      - "path/folder:/var/jenkins_home"
```

You can see this real example

```
jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 50000:50000
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/data/jenkin_vol:/var/jenkins_home"
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dhudson.footerURL=http://mycompany.com
    networks:
      - my_network
```