# Jenkins no initialAdminPassword: No such file or directory

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

When i do

```
# cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
cat: /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword: No such file or directory
```

- I have created a test user
- In users folder only the test user is there i dont see any admin user is there
- also I am not able to create users with test user beacuase of no admin privilege

how can i get admin password

Comment: possible duplicate of > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167081/docker-jenkins-images-login-error

Answer (score 1):

$ docker exec  cat var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

remove the slash before 'var' and it will work fine

Comment: It worked even with a "/" for me. Thanks for the info @PolsaniSandeep

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Ubuntu switch to root user "sudo su"

then try to see the content of the file.

I tried that running ubuntu on EC2 instance. good luck

Answer (score 0):

cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

cat: /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword: No such file or directory

Is used for finding the initial password of admin 
start the Jenkins navigate to /var/lib/Jenkins/
find it over there

or

You have to start your Jenkins server and then execute

sudo more /var/log/jenkins.log